# Sidekiq - Enqueuing a job to be performed 0.seconds from now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I'm using sidekiq for background job and I enqueue a job like this:

```
SampleJob.set(wait: waiting_time.to_i.seconds).perform_later(***)　・・・ ①
```

When `waiting_time` is nil,
it becomes

```
SampleJob.set(wait: 0.seconds).perform_later(***)
```

Of course it works well, but I'm worried about performance because worker enqueued with wait argument is derived by poller,
so I wonder if I should remove `set(wait: waiting_time.to_i.seconds)` when
waiting_time is nil.

i.e.)

```
if waiting_time.present?
  SampleJob.set(wait: waiting_time.to_i.seconds).perform_later(***)
else
  SampleJob.perform_later(***)
end ・・・ ②
```

Is there any differences in performance or speed between ① and ②？
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. It looks like this is already considered in the Sidekiq library.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/main/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb#L261

```
# Optimization to enqueue something now that is scheduled to go out now or in the past
@opts["at"] = ts if ts > now
```

Comment: Thank you for your really helpful answer.

Comment: Only true for Sidekiq native jobs, not ActiveJobs.